# Private members in Model

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm working with play.

I defined a private member in my model, hoping that JPA
wouldn't try to handle it.

For some reason I get this error :

A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Could not determine type for:     java.util.Map, at table: User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(myPrivateMember)]

How can I declare such private members without JPA crashing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [@Transient](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation. It tells that the member is not persistable.